# Rules url regex

Tags: regex, redirect, rules

I am creating a rule to redirect

```
www.<url>.com/overview           to   www.<url>.com/history
www.<url>.com/overview/history   to   www.<url>.com/history

  <rule name="Overview" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/overview" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.<url>.com/history" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="Overview-History" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/overview/history" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.<url>.com/history" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

The above rules are working but is there a way to combine two urls into one rule rather than creating two different rules?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/overview(/(history|mission|vision))?$" />
```

Comment: thanks i tried this but even /overview/history/123 or  /overview/history0 is redirecting to www.<url>.com/history

Comment: thanks just last thing if i have /overview/vision or overview/mission and redirects to the same "www.<url>.com/history" page?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed: I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: currently /overview and /overview/history are redirecting to www.<url>.com/history

But i also want /overview/vision and overview/mission wants to be redirect to the same www.<url>.com/history